# Recommended Approach When Building Notification Panel with WebSocket and React

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, stompjs

I am building a notification panel using websocket and react. Should i use redux toolkit or  useContext for managing centralize location of websockets? or is there any other suggested approach i can use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redux** is highly has optimized store-update mechanism and can handle large-scale applications, when dealing with complex state management and especially for large applications with deeply nested components or multiple layers of state. However **useContext** can work just fine for smaller apps or components where performance is not critical concern.